# Bootstrap 4 Tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap 4 for creating tooltips on my web page. But somehow the tooltip is not working properly. 
Below is the code for the same:

```
<a href="#reserve-table" class="btn btn-warning" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top" title="or Call us at<br><strong>+852 1234 5678</strong>">Reserve Table</a>
```

I have included the below files:

```
bootstrap.min.js
bootstrap.min.css
```

I have also activated the tooltip with the following js code:``

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); });
```

Can someone help with this ?
This is how the tooltip looks on my web page.
[Tooltip on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRVHV.jpg)

Comment: "But somehow the tooltip is not working properly" what is not working properly? what is it doing, what is it suppost to do?

Comment: also since you did not tag jquery but use jquery code, did you include a jquery library?

Comment: Yes I have added the jquery and popper librabry as well.

Comment: I have added the jquery and popper library as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have the tooltip display on the page when ready you could use the:
`.tooltip('show')` or `.tooltip('toggle')` to bypass the default hover trigger.

There are more javascript options for tooltips from here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/#options

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `nav-link` class along with btn and btn-warning. Also make sure all the JS files are in order i.e. first you have jquery than popper and bootstrap.min.js at last.

Comment: What is not working? The tooltip doesn't even show up? Do you have a github repo for this that we can see?